# A friend of mine installed macos on vmware

Tags: windows, mac, vmware

Yet my Windows computer cannot see the file on that Mac vmware

We can see the files on the physical iMac.

What settings I should use?

The vmware Mac can see windows file though.

Comment: Technically you cannot run a OS X virtual machine on a non-Apple computer. Apple goes to great lengths to make this very hard. VMWare also honors Apple's license agreement. The reason it works on the IMac is clear, its an Apple computer, this support is built into Mac OS X.  Please take the time to clarify your question...It is VERY VERY poorly worded.

Comment: the vmware is on mac. You can run macos on vmware. The vmware need to be on mac.

Comment: @JimThio Did you mean "A friend of mine installed *windows* on vmware?"

Comment: I would imagine that he's running a Mac OS VM (the virtualisation software is VMware, which plays nice with virtualising Mac OS). The virtual Mac OS shares some files on a network, but Windows can't see them. A physical iMac can, however. I would guess the sharing isn't set up properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have File Sharing turned on while the MacOS VM is running. You should be able to choose which directories and what protocol you want to use.

As has been mentioned before there are propietary reasons, plus Mac OS X partition format is different from those used on windows and windows cannot directly access it. Legal intermediaries like VMWare will enforce the walled garden.